# Index multiple arrays in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have documents that look like this:

```
    ...
    propA:[0, 2, 6],      //Array of unique numbers of length max. ~50
    propB:[2, 14, 24, 39],//Array of unique numbers of length max. ~50
    propC:[1, 14, 29],    //Array of unique numbers of length max. ~50
    ...
```

And I want to be able to query them in a such a way that :

- I can match all documents with certain properties
- I can match all documents without certain properties

For example, at the moment I use the query:

```
mongo.db.collection('things').find({
    propA:{$all:[...], $nin:[...]},
    propB:{$all:[...], $nin:[...]},
    propC:{$all:[...], $nin:[...]},
})
```

But it's really slow and scales really badly because mongo has to scan every documents.

The solutions to make mongo queries faster are:

- Make an index
- Change document schema
- Both

The problem is that I cannot `.createIndex({propA:1, propB:1, propC: 1})` because mongo does not accept to index multiple array fields (for good reasons).

But when I use another schema like:

```
    ...
    props:["a0", "a2", "a6", "b2", "b14", "b24", "b39", "c1", "c14", "c29"]
    ...
```

And create an index on `{props: 1}`, querying the same way as above executes like this:

- first stage: IXSCAN, incredibly fast, but it only selects the first property (ex: "a0")
- second stage: FETCH, incredibly slow, has to scan all documents that passed the IXSCAN

So my question is :

How to query documents with arrays the most efficiently ?

Comment: Have you tried creating three indexes - one for each `propX`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs As I said, it's not possible in mongo, due to the way it indexes arrays by splitting them, indexes with multiple arrays could get out of hand

Comment: I meant three _independent_ multikey indexes - like shown in the `"indexes"` configuration [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/exAAwupJm7w).

Comment: Although, looking at [`explain`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/exAAwupJm7w), it seems to be virtually the same as you describe for having a single multikey index.  It's curious why an index intersection is not performed.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thanks for the help, I did not know the website you gave. It's curious but it's due to the architecture of indexes. From what I know it's binary trees, so making a union is quite difficult as you can see in this conference : youtu.be/2NDr57QERYA (from about 11 mins, "performance issues", really interesting stuff )

Comment: Have you tried looking into creating a specific view and indexing on that instead? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/create-view/

Comment: @dangarfield I thinked about it but the problem is the same, what is the optimal data structure to make the queries I show ? How does views can help ?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I found the answer, strangely it's regex =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the OP, I think I found the "optimal" way to do it : regex

For example, instead of storing

```
    propA:[0, 2, 6],
    propB:[2, 14, 24, 39],
    propC:[1, 14, 29],
```

You store

```
props: "a0a2a6b2b14b24b39c1c14c29" //a string, really
```

You create the index `.createIndex({"props": "text"})`

And for example to search for documents with a1, b5, b7 and without a3, b4 and c8 you query:

```
mongo.db.collection('things').find({
    props: {
        $regex: /.*a1.*^a3.*^b4.*b5.*b7.*c8/
    }
})
```

Thinking about it I have no idea how it's possible to query a collection with millions of documents in few ms, but the nice thing is that it is.

There is only one "small" problem:

- Query for properties higher than all documents.

Strangely, if the maximum propA of the collection is 19 and you query for 20 mongo does scan all documents instead of using the index, I guess an easy fix is to add "x999" between the series but still, it's pretty ugly.

For example, you store :

```
props: "a0a2a6a999b2b14b24b39b999c1c14c29c999" //another string
```

I am still looking forward to better alternative, indeed, you cannot make a compound index like `.createIndex({"location": "2dsphere", "props": "text"})`.

Comment: Very interesting! Are you sure this uses the "text" index?  I thought the "text" index was only used by the `"$text"` operator. I hope you have better luck with negative substring matches than I have had - I seem to be a "gotcha" generator.  :-)

Comment: It doesn't use the text index - I'm (slowly) drafting an answer that mentions this and provides some more context

Comment: @user20042973 What do you mean by "It doesn't use the text index" ? Are you talking about my answer or rick's comment ?

Comment: @user20042973 Could you please tell me what doesnt use the text index please ? From my tests, doing like I did uses it, I'm really confused with your comment. I'm going to implement this solution, I dont want it to be suboptimal if possible and have to redo it latter